# Jssor slider navigator arrows not working outside of the slider in Safari

Tags: safari, jssor

I have issue with jssor slider navigator arrows. I want to use them outside of the slider. They work fine outside on all browsers, except Safari. Is there any solution for this issue. Thank you in advance!

Comment: what's the os and browser version? any url I can access online?

Comment: Windows 7 , Safari 5.1.7, the website is under construction, it is not online yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep size of 'slides container' original, and then make the size of 'outer container' bigger.
In this manner, you will see arrows beside.

And then adjust position (style="...top: ...px; ...left: ...px;...") of 'slides container', you can make 'slides container' center to 'outer container'.

See <s>[slider with arrows outside](http://www.jssor.com/carouselslider/slider.html)</s>.